# How to Make Retrofit API calls inside Service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, retrofit2

I'm trying to retrieve data from database and display the result as a toast message (planning to do more after I get it working).However, it's giving me the error - "unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and telling me the case is "        Call> call = apiServiceNotif.getNotifications(id, onReceive);"

I'm calling the callback function inside [ onStartCommand ] like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      getMessage("1"); //for testing
      return START_STICKY;
}
```

I've tested the callback function on another class and worked fine. It's my first time working with services so I'm honestly kinda lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my callback function:

```
public void getMessage(String id){
        ApiServiceMessage apiServiceMessage = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiServiceMessage.class);
        Call<List<Messsages>> call = apiServiceMessage.getMessages(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Messages>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Messages>> call,
                                   Response<List<Messages>> response) {
                List<Messages> messages= response.body();

                 for(Messages m: messages){
                     Toast(getApplicationContext(), m.getMessageTitle + " " + m.getMessageContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Messages>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to load." + t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Post your error log here too. And I cannot find `apiServiceNotif.getNotifications(id, onReceive);` call in the code you posted.

Comment: Try to disable Instant Run and it might solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal when I asked the question was to use a service that retrieves messages from the API every 4 hours and turn them into notifications. This was back when I didn't know I can use GCM / Firebase to send out notifications.